# Form submit not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome, form-submit

So I am converting some old code to be compatable with Chrome and for whateve reason, the code I had for printing a report (opening it in a new tab) isn't working in Chrome but is fine in IE.  I've tried all kinds of different ways with type button and submit, and have poured all over this side and haven't had any results.

This input is inside the form "frmDisplay"

```
<input type="button" id="servlet" name="servlet" value=" Print "
       onclick="return printOrder()" />
```

This is my code that submits the reports

```
function printOrder() {
    if (AnyChecked()) {
        document.frmDisplay.action = 'PrintOrder.cs';

        copyValue = document.getElementById('KanbanCopyNumber').getAttribute('value');

        var arrayP = createHiddenElement('ARRAY_PARAMETERS', 'orderNumber');
        document.frmDisplay.appendChild(arrayP);
        document.frmDisplay.target = "_blank";

        var copyNumber = document.createElement('INPUT');
        copyNumber.type = 'hidden';
        copyNumber.name = 'CopyNumber';
        copyNumber.value = copyValue;
        document.frmDisplay.appendChild(copyNumber);
        document.frmDisplay.target = "_blank";

        reportName = document.frmDisplay.rep.getAttribute('value');

        if (labels.length == 1) {
            reportName = labels[0];
        }
        else {
            if (reportName == null || reportName == '') {
                reportName = 'All';
            }
        }
        if (reportName != 'All') {
            document.frmDisplay.rep.value = reportName;
            document.frmDisplay.submit();
        }
        else {
            for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                document.frmDisplay.rep.value = labels[i];
                document.frmDisplay.submit();
            }
            document.frmDisplay.rep.value = 'All';
        }
        for (index = document.frmDisplay.length; index >= 0; index--) {
            childElem = document.frmDisplay.childNodes[index];
        }

        // Force refresh of the view

        callSubmit();
    }
    else {
        alert('To generate report at least one order must be selected');
    }
    return false;
}
```

Heres the form in its entirety.

```
<form name="frmDisplay" method="post" onSubmit="document.getElementById('submit').disabled=true;">
<input type="hidden" name="direction">
<table width="100%" valign="top" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td width="340">
<div class="nav">
<strong><font color="#db0055"><img width="15" src="images/shim.gif">Orders&nbsp;<input type="text" name="startRow" size="5" value="0">-0  of 0</font></strong>
</div>
</td><td><img width="15" src="images/shim.gif"><font color="blue">This page will refresh every 5 minutes</font></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="tabularData" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr id="controlRow" class="controlRow">
<td nowrap="true" colspan="10"><input type="button" id="servlet" name="servlet" value=" Print " onclick="return printOrder()"> 
            &nbsp;checked orders for report&nbsp;
            <input type="hidden" id="rep" name="rep"><script type="text/javascript">
                var labelArray = new Array();
                var labels = new Array();

                            labelArray[0] = new Option("All", "All", "", "selected");
                        labelArray[1] = new Option("2x4 Roll - Proximity", "ek_proximity.jasper");labels[0] = "ek_proximity.jasper";labelArray[2] = new Option("2x4 Roll Label - Rainbird";
                writeSelectBox(labelArray, "rep1", 1, "document.frmDisplay.rep.value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value", "z-index: 99");
           </script>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <b># of copies</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="KanbanCopyNumber" value="1" size="2" maxlength="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="headerRowRefresh">
<!--FILTER GOES HERE-->
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
                               var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();//'CalDiv');
                    </SCRIPT><td colspan="10">
        Display
        <input type="hidden" name="pageSize" value="20"><script type="text/javascript">
            var pageArray = new Array();
            pageArray[0] = new Option("10", "10");pageArray[1] = new Option("20", "20", "", "selected");pageArray[2] = new Option("50", "50");pageArray[3] = new Option("100", "100");
            writeSelectBox(pageArray, "pageSize1", 1, "document.frmDisplay.pageSize.value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value", "font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 10px;z-index: 99");
        </script>
        matches per page
        <input type="hidden" name="pageNbr" value="1">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input name="submitButton" onClick="callSubmit(); return false;" type="submit" value="Refresh Data">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input name="submitButton" onclick="callResetFilter(); return false;" type="submit" value="Reset Filters"><input type="hidden" name="cmdQuery"></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<td valign="top">
<table class="tabularData" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%">
<tr>
<td>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr class="headerRowTitle" height="23" valign="top">
<td>&nbsp;</td><td nowrap="true">Order#</td><td nowrap="true">Printed</td><td nowrap="true">Status</td>
</tr>
<tr class="headerRow" height="28" valign="top">
<td>&nbsp;</td><td nowrap="true"><input align="left" size="10" name="filterOrder" value=""></td><td nowrap="true"><input type="hidden" name="filterPrinted"><script type="text/javascript">
            var optionArray = new Array();
            optionArray[0] = new Option(" - All - ", " ", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[1] = new Option("Yes", "1", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[2] = new Option("No", "0", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;", "selected");document.frmDisplay.filterPrinted.value="0";optionArray[3] = new Option("N/A", "-1", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");writeSelectBox(optionArray, "filterPrinted1", 1, "document.frmDisplay.filterPrinted.value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value", "font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 10px;vertical-align: middle;z-index: 0;width:120");</script></td><td nowrap="true"><input type="hidden" name="status"><script type="text/javascript">
            var optionArray = new Array();
            optionArray[0] = new Option(" - All - ", " ", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[1] = new Option("Not Canceled", "P", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[2] = new Option("Open", "O", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[3] = new Option("Waiting Approval", "A", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[4] = new Option("Partially Received", "R", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[5] = new Option("Sent", "S", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[6] = new Option("Canceled", "X", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[7] = new Option("Closed", "Z", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");writeSelectBox(optionArray, "status1", 1, "document.frmDisplay.status.value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value", "font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 10px;vertical-align: middle;z-index: 0;width:120");</script></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td><td align="left" valign="top">
<table class="tabularData" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%">
<tr>
<td width="100%">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" id="scrollTable">
<tr class="headerRowTitle" height="23" valign="top">
<td nowrap="true">Part#</td><td nowrap="true">Location</td><td nowrap="true">Site</td><td nowrap="true">Price</td><td nowrap="true">Mfr</td><td nowrap="true">Mfr Part#</td><td nowrap="true">Qty</td><td nowrap="true">Qty Open</td><td nowrap="true">Supplier</td><td nowrap="true">PO</td><td nowrap="true">PO Line</td><td nowrap="true">Date Created</td><td nowrap="true">Due Date</td><td nowrap="true">User</td><td nowrap="true">Buyer</td><td nowrap="true">Note</td><td nowrap="true">O1</td><td nowrap="true">O2</td><td nowrap="true">O3</td><td nowrap="true">F4</td><td nowrap="true">F10</td>
</tr>
<tr class="headerRow" height="28" valign="top">
<td><input align="left" size="15" name="filterPart" value=""></td><td><input align="left" size="10" name="filterLocation" value=""></td><td><input type="hidden" name="filterSite"><script type="text/javascript">
            var optionArray = new Array();
            optionArray[0] = new Option(" - All - ", "", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[1] = new Option("007", "007", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[2] = new Option("07", "07", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[3] = new Option("081730", "081730", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[4] = new Option("11", "11", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[5] = new Option("12", "12", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[6] = new Option("13", "13", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[7] = new Option("13&", "13&", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[8] = new Option("14", "14", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[9] = new Option("140", "140", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[10] = new Option("15", "15", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[11] = new Option("16", "16", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[12] = new Option("19", "19", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[13] = new Option("2001", "2001", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[14] = new Option("2002", "2002", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[15] = new Option("32", "32", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[16] = new Option("400", "400", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[17] = new Option("402", "402", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[18] = new Option("403", "403", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[19] = new Option("41", "41", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[20] = new Option("604", "604", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[21] = new Option("605", "605", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[22] = new Option("680", "680", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[23] = new Option("69", "69", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[24] = new Option("786104", "786104", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[25] = new Option("87", "87", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[26] = new Option("A1A", "A1A", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[27] = new Option("ARG", "ARG", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[28] = new Option("AVK", "AVK", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[29] = new Option("AVNET", "AVNET", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[30] = new Option("B1", "B1", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[31] = new Option("BBY", "BBY", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[32] = new Option("D1", "D1", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[33] = new Option("DAL", "DAL", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[34] = new Option("DEL1", "DEL1", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[35] = new Option("DEL10", "DEL10", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[36] = new Option("DEL11", "DEL11", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[37] = new Option("DEL12", "DEL12", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[38] = new Option("DEL13", "DEL13", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[39] = new Option("DEL14", "DEL14", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[40] = new Option("DEL15", "DEL15", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[41] = new Option("DEL16", "DEL16", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[42] = new Option("DEL17", "DEL17", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[43] = new Option("DEL18", "DEL18", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[44] = new Option("DEL19", "DEL19", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[45] = new Option("DEL2", "DEL2", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[46] = new Option("DEL20", "DEL20", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[47] = new Option("DEL21", "DEL21", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[48] = new Option("DEL22", "DEL22", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[49] = new Option("DEL3", "DEL3", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[50] = new Option("DEL4", "DEL4", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[51] = new Option("DEL5", "DEL5", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[52] = new Option("DEL6", "DEL6", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[53] = new Option("DEL7", "DEL7", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[54] = new Option("DEL8", "DEL8", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[55] = new Option("DEL9", "DEL9", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[56] = new Option("ECONTROLS", "ECONTROLS", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[57] = new Option("ECT", "ECT", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[58] = new Option("FL01", "FL01", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[59] = new Option("FL04", "FL04", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[60] = new Option("FWB", "FWB", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[61] = new Option("LEX", "LEX", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[62] = new Option("MAIN", "MAIN", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[63] = new Option("MANKATO", "MANKATO", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[64] = new Option("MIL", "MIL", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[65] = new Option("MIS", "MIS", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[66] = new Option("PITT", "PITT", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[67] = new Option("RECEIPT", "RECEIPT", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[68] = new Option("ST5678", "ST5678", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[69] = new Option("STP", "STP", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[70] = new Option("STPETER", "STPETER", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[71] = new Option("TENN", "TENN", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[72] = new Option("TMP", "TMP", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[73] = new Option("TMP2", "TMP2", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[74] = new Option("TOR", "TOR", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[75] = new Option("VAN", "VAN", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[76] = new Option("VMI", "VMI", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[77] = new Option("WNJ", "WNJ", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");writeSelectBox(optionArray, "filterSite1", 1, "document.frmDisplay.filterSite.value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value", "font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 10px;vertical-align: middle;z-index: 0;width:97;");</script></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input align="left" size="10" name="filterMfr" value=""></td><td><input align="left" size="15" name="filterMFRPart" value=""></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="hidden" name="filterSupplier"><script type="text/javascript">
            var optionArray = new Array();
            optionArray[0] = new Option(" - All - ", "", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[1] = new Option("36", "36", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[2] = new Option("41", "41", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[3] = new Option("41.1", "41.1", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[4] = new Option("AAAA", "AAAA", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[5] = new Option("ACME", "ACME", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[6] = new Option("ARGH", "ARGH", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[7] = new Option("AVIMP1", "AVIMP1", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[8] = new Option("AVNET", "AVNET", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[9] = new Option("AVT", "AVT", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[10] = new Option("BRADB3", "BRADB3", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[11] = new Option("BRET", "BRET", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[12] = new Option("DEL ME", "DEL ME", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[13] = new Option("EBV", "EBV", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[14] = new Option("EM1", "EM1", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[15] = new Option("EM2", "EM2", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[16] = new Option("GAEDKE", "GAEDKE", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[17] = new Option("GPSI", "GPSI", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[18] = new Option("HENRYT", "HENRYT", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[19] = new Option("HEX", "HEX", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[20] = new Option("IMS", "IMS", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[21] = new Option("MILLER", "MILLER", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[22] = new Option("PACKSP", "PACKSP", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[23] = new Option("RIEMER", "RIEMER", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[24] = new Option("ROARK", "ROARK", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[25] = new Option("SCS", "SCS", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[26] = new Option("SILICA", "SILICA", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[27] = new Option("TIME", "TIME", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");optionArray[28] = new Option("WBC", "WBC", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;");writeSelectBox(optionArray, "filterSupplier1", 1, "document.frmDisplay.filterSupplier.value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value", "font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 10px;vertical-align: middle;z-index: 0;width:70");</script></td><td><input align="left" size="10" name="filterPO" value=""></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input align="left" size="12" name="fromDate" value="24-FEB-2014"><A HREF="#" name="ffromDate" id="ffromDate" onClick="cal1.select(document.frmDisplay.fromDate,'ffromDate','dd-MMM-yyyy'); return false;"><img src="images/calendar.gif" style="vertical-align: bottom; border: 0px;"></A>
        to
        <input align="left" size="12" name="toDate" value=""><A HREF="#" name="tfromDate" id="tfromDate" onClick="cal1.select(document.frmDisplay.toDate,'tfromDate','dd-MMM-yyyy'); return false;"><img src="images/calendar.gif" style="vertical-align: bottom; border: 0px;"></A></td><td><input align="left" size="12" name="fromDateLate" value=""><A HREF="#" name="ffromDateLate" id="ffromDateLate" onClick="cal1.select(document.frmDisplay.fromDateLate,'ffromDateLate','dd-MMM-yyyy'); return false;"><img src="images/calendar.gif" style="vertical-align: bottom; border: 0px;"></A>
        to
        <input align="left" size="12" name="toDateLate" value=""><A HREF="#" name="tfromDateLate" id="tfromDateLate" onClick="cal1.select(document.frmDisplay.toDateLate,'tfromDateLate','dd-MMM-yyyy'); return false;"><img src="images/calendar.gif" style="vertical-align: bottom; border: 0px;"></A></td><td><input align="left" size="10" name="filterUser" value=""></td><td><input align="left" size="10" name="filterBuyer" value=""></td><td><input align="left" size="10" name="filterNote" value=""></td><td nowrap="true">&nbsp;</td><td nowrap="true">&nbsp;</td><td nowrap="true">&nbsp;</td><td nowrap="true">&nbsp;</td><td nowrap="true">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="footerRow">
<td colspan="10"><a href="javascript:setChecked(1)">Check All</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="javascript:setChecked(0)">Clear All</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="100%" valign="top" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td>
<div class="nav">
<strong><font color="#db0055"><img width="15" src="images/shim.gif">Orders&nbsp;<input type="text" name="startRow" size="5" value="0">-0  of 0</font></strong>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Can u show the rest of HTML for the from please?

Comment: why the return in onclick ?

Comment: @LabibIsmaiel - If it returns false, it prevents the default behavior.  Returning false is the equivalent of calling `event.preventDefault()` in the handler.

Comment: Since you are on `type=button` you're not triggering a submit, hence nothing to return to, just executing `printOrder()`. Your submit can be found in `callSubmit()`. Assuming the proper form will be selected and submitted?

Comment: form.action points to C# file? what is the expected result of multiple form.submit inside the for loop?

Comment: It's actually not a C# file, it just goes back to our PrintOrder.xsl file, not sure why we use cs but it works in every other case.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.getAttribute('value')`.  Use `.value` instead.

```
copyValue = document.getElementById('KanbanCopyNumber').value;
...
reportName = document.frmDisplay.rep.value;
```

The former will get you the value contained in the HTML.  If the user updates the value of the field, the `value` property will reflect that change, but the `value` attribute will not.

Comment: Odd.  In some cases when trying to make it compatible in Chrome, was getting errors when using .value so had to change some of them to getAttribute.  Think most of that was with the innerHTML though.